# Select elements with selectors in jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, select, checkbox

I have a nested list with checkboxes.
With the first checkbox i want to toggle all the checkboxes in that list.
I know how to toggle them with jQUery but i don't know how to select them.
Thats the problem, the selecting part.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p> lorem ipsum </p>
        <ul class="list">
            <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p> lorem ipsum </p>
        <ul class="list">
            <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I have read your request correctly;

jQuery [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Exampe: http://jsfiddle.net/52DBv/

Comment: Does he want them to be "checked" ie. "selected" Rest of it is awesome. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".list").find("input[type=checkbox]:first").on("click", function(){
    var cb = $(this);
    cb.parents(".list").find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", cb.is(":checked"));
});​
```

**Edit**: Sorry, working for the second list now.

Comment: This won't work as expected as it will add the click handler to all `input[type=checkbox]`es, since they are all the "first" of their `<li>`.

Comment: It wasn't adding the handler to all checkboxes because I had :first on my selector. But it wasn't working for the second list. The updated version is: http://jsfiddle.net/CJwka/

Answer (score 0):

You could go with something like this:

**HTML**:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p> lorem ipsum </p>
        <ul class="list">
            <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p> lorem ipsum </p>
        <ul class="list">
            <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>​
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".list li:first-child input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
    if (!this.checked) {
        $(this).parents(".list").find("input[type=checkbox]").removeAttr(    "disabled");
    } else {
        $(this).parents(".list").find("input[type=checkbox]").attr(    "disabled", true);
        $(this).parents(".list").find("li:first-child input[type=checkbox]"    ).removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});​
```

you can see a live working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ramsesoriginal/GQTtU/embedded/result/), or look at the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ramsesoriginal/GQTtU/).
As so often is the case, there are plenty of possible solutions, but this could work.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect all the checkbox inside an element with class "list" as follows:

```
$('.list input:checkbox')
```

So, something like this should work:

```
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p> lorem ipsum </p>
            <ul class="list">
                <li><input type="checkbox" onclick="$('.list input:checkbox').attr('checked', true);"></li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p> lorem ipsum </p>
            <ul class="list">
                <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
     </ul>
```

(you must add the "toggle" logic)

Check [jq](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) for more information con jquery checkbox selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
$('.list').find('input:eq(0)'​)​.on('click', function(){        
    var $checkbox = $(this).is(':checked');
    $(this).closest('ul').find('input').attr('checked', $checkbox);
});​​​
```